# Saving audio files in document's folder of iPhone and later delete it when uploaded to the server?

Tags: iphone, database, audio

I have a situation where I will be recording audio files and save it into the documents folder of the app until the user uploads it to the server. The audio recorder will record the sound and it will save the file in the documents folder as he comes out of the audio recording screen. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: The question is how to save that audio file for a finite time in the document's folder?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Path to the documents directory:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *filePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
```

Saving the data (an NSData) to the documents directory:

```
BOOL status = [NSDictionary writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```

Deleting the file after the upload the the server:

```
BOOL status = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:filePath error:nil];
```